# Android apk too big using OpenCV and Nd4j

Tags: java, android, opencv, nd4j

I have an android application that needs the OpenCV and Nd4j libraries.
The problem is, the app is too big (almost 700MB), and i have no idea how to slim it down.

build.gradle:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nd4j/nd4j-api
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-api', version: '1.0.0-beta7'
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version: '1.0.0-beta7'
implementation group: 'org.datavec', name: 'datavec-data-image', version: '1.0.0-beta7'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Here is the apk itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OZ2y.png

How can i reduce the size?

Comment: I'm not an android dev, but it seems your shading a lot of libs. You probably shouldn't shade OpenCV

Comment: Yes i know, but OpenCV uses the library for different architectures, in this case Nd4j is bigger than OpenCV, i would like to delete the unnecessary libraries..

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies

Comment: Like this https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/android/setup ?